# What's the fastest collision detection (Game Maker)

Tags: collision-detection, performance

I want to build a simulator using Game Maker in which there are many (up to hundreds) of `obj_Cell`, each has a radius of 10, (they don't have sprites, they just draw a circle with radius 10).

Each step, I want the cells to check around itself for `obj_A` to see if any `obj_A` is "touching" it, (has a distance less than 10 from the cell). However, since I have so many `obj_Cell` and so many `obj_A`, the most straight forward code (below) will have to be executed tens of thousands of times (number of obj_A * number of obj_Cell)

```
//In obj_Cell:
(with obj_A)
{
   if distance_to_object(other)<=10
   {
      //do stuff
   }
}
```

Is there any possible way to make this faster?

Comment: Have you done any research into spatial partitioning?

Comment: Do you mean the idea of dividing the room into parts and assigning colliding objects in one of those parts and checking only in adjacent parts for collision? I think I understand the basic, but how would I implement such a thing?